# Styles metadata is not included in release build?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm using the reflection classes of Flex and I've notice when I publish in debug all of a components style metadata is found by describeType. But if I create a release build none of the styles show up.

Comment: What do you need the style metadata for at runtime?  You can add it into the release build using a compiler argument; perhaps it isn't added by default because it serves no runtime purpose.  Without looking; IT hink the compiler argument is keep-as-metadata or something similar.  Some of the frameworks such as Swiz use this.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks. I'm working on listing out the styles a component has. Sort of a style explorer.

Comment: It's -keep-as3-metadata+=Style. Want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add metadata into a release build using the compiler argument keep-as-metadata.  The default Flex configuration probably doesn't include the style metadata because it is not used at runtime.

This compiler argument will keep the style metadata in there when creating a release build:

```
keep-as3-metadata+=Style
```